# corrupted image uploading in cpanel with 404 error

Tags: angular, spring, image, http-status-code-404

I have a problem while uploading an image in an FTP server (using Cpanel) in production env with spring and angular technology.
The file is uploaded to the specified folder tmp but the image uploaded is corrupted and cannot be shown with this error 404 (Not Found).
When i upload the same image manually from cPanel, it works perfectly.
Any propositions please :)
Here is the source code :

public class FTPService {

```
static FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
static String TMP_UPLOAD_FOLDER = "/home/myproject/public_html/tmp/";
static String SERVER_DOMAIN = " XX.XXX.XX.XX";
static String SERVER_USERNAME = "username1";
static String SERVER_PASSWORD = "myPassword";

public static String uFileUpload(MultipartFile file, String TypePhoto, Long clientId) throws IOException {
    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Empty File");
        return "Empty File";
    } else {
        // dossier TMP
        File f1 = new File(TMP_UPLOAD_FOLDER);
        boolean bool = f1.mkdir();
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        Path path = Paths.get(TMP_UPLOAD_FOLDER + file.getOriginalFilename());
        System.out.println(path.toString());
        Files.write(path, bytes);
        System.out.println("File successfully uploaded to local storage : " + file.getOriginalFilename());
        ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
        int reply;
        ftp.connect(SERVER_DOMAIN);
        reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            ftp.disconnect();
            System.out.println("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
        }
        ftp.login(SERVER_USERNAME, SERVER_PASSWORD);
        ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftp.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        try {
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(TMP_UPLOAD_FOLDER + file.getOriginalFilename()));
            System.out.println(input);
            ftp.storeFile("/home/myproject/public_html/tmp/" + file.getOriginalFilename().toString()+"", input);
            ftp.logout();
            ftp.disconnect();
            System.out.println("File Uploaded !");
            input.close();
            Files.delete(path);
            System.out.println("File deleted");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error uploading file to remote server");
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: 404 doesn't sound like a corrupted image, I would expect a 400 (bad request) in that case. Are you sure the path and all is correct?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm the file is uploaded in ftp server but when i tries to access to it, the image is not shown with 404 error. If i change the uploaded file manually without modifying anything in database or in the code, it works